# Knockout JS $data binding context

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

When I pass the $data object that is the result of a foreach loop to a typescript function, I'm able to access the loop items.  When I pass a $data object from anything other than a foreach loop to a typescript function, I see function signatures and other properties and objects, but no data.

What I want to do is access any response data from a page just like I can access data from a foreach loop.  How can I do this?

Comment: Show us the code

Answer (score 1):

$data is the view model object in the current context. Hence, within a loop it is the object in the the array your looping but outsite the loop it is not that object anymore.  Refer to [Knockout reference](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html) to get ideas and understand the different contexts.

Comment: Understood.  Is there a way in knockout to have the scope or context be the entire page in which I can traverse the DOM to get the data from any element?

Comment: The $root is the top parent. The object you passed to apply bindings knockout function. You should be able to get any data from the top object.